# MultiTenant custom ILogger - cannot consume scoped service from singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, saaskit

i'm trying to add tenant name to every log done by asp.net core.
Im using [Sasskit](https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit) for multi-tenant.

And im getting some scope problems. I would like some feedback on how i can get this to work:

This is my custom logger:

```
public class MultiTenantLogger : IMultiTenantProvider
{
    private AppTenant _tenant;

    public MultiTenantLogger(AppTenant tenant)
    {
        _tenant = tenant;
    }

    public string GetTenantName<T>()
    {
        var typeDisplayName = GetTypeDisplayName(typeof(T));

        if (_tenant == null)
        {
            return typeDisplayName;
        }

        return $"Tenant: {_tenant.Name}";
    }

}
```

.

```
public class MultiTenantLogger<T> : ILogger<T>
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public MultiTenantLogger(ILoggerFactory factory, IMultiTenantProvider multiTenantProvider)
    {
        if (factory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factory));
        }
        if (multiTenantProvider == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(multiTenantProvider));
        }

        var category = multiTenantProvider.GetTenantName<T>();
        _logger = factory.CreateLogger(category);
    }

    IDisposable ILogger.BeginScope<TState>(TState state) => _logger.BeginScope(state);

    bool ILogger.IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) => _logger.IsEnabled(logLevel);

    void ILogger.Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel,
                             EventId eventId,
                             TState state,
                             Exception exception,
                             Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
        => _logger.Log(logLevel, eventId, state, exception, formatter);
 }
```

This is my startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    _services = services;
    services.AddMultitenancy<AppTenant, CachingAppTenantResolver>();

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

    services.Configure<MultitenancyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Multitenancy"));

    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddTransient<IMultiTenantProvider, MultiTenantLogger>();
    services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(MultiTenantLogger<>)));
}
```

I get this error:

> **Cannot consume scoped service 'AspNetMvcSampleModels.AppTenant'
>   from singleton 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IApplicationLifetime'.**

Any feedback on how to get this working is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to make both Singleton or Scoped

you can try to replace

```
services.AddTransient<IMultiTenantProvider, MultiTenantLogger>();
```

with

```
services.AddSingleton<IMultiTenantProvider, MultiTenantLogger>();
```